# Get adapter items in Android

Tags: android, android-adapter

I have an AutoCompleteTextView filled with an ArrayAdapter of strings. I add on my adapter some string dynamically:

```
adapter.add("foo");
```

But I want to check if the string that I want to add to the adapter is already inside it, and for doing this, I think it is necessary to get all the items contents in the adapter for checking them.

I've tried to use:

```
adapter.getItem(position)
```

But it doesn't work and crashes my app. How can I check the strings in the adapter?

#### Code

```
public class myTTSActivity extends Activity {
    private TextToSpeech tts;
    private AutoCompleteTextView txtText;
    private int prefN;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    private static final String PREF_NAME = "PREF_STR";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        tts = new TextToSpeech(this, null);

        prefN = 0;
        Button btnOk = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnOk);
        txtText = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.txtTesto);
        txtText.setThreshold(0);

         adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this,
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,
                new String[] {}
        );

        txtText.setAdapter(adapter);

        btnOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Prendo stringa textBox
                String str = txtText.getText().toString();

                // Faccio parlare con il testo
                tts.setLanguage(Locale.ITALIAN);
                tts.speak(str, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);

                // Stampo Toast
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                // Inserisco SharedPreference
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, 0).edit().putString("p"+prefN, str);
                editor.commit();

                txtText.setText("");

                combo();
            }
        });
    }

    public void combo()
    {
        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, 0);

        adapter.add(pref.getString("p"+prefN, ""));

        adapter.getItem(0);
    }
}
```

#### logcat output

```
01-12 12:10:18.683: ERROR/cutils-trace(1234): Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
01-12 12:10:47.164: ERROR/SoundPool(297): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
01-12 12:10:47.164: ERROR/SoundPool(297): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
01-12 12:10:47.164: ERROR/SoundPool(297): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
01-12 12:10:47.164: ERROR/SoundPool(297): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
01-12 12:10:47.173: ERROR/SoundPool(297): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
01-12 12:10:47.173: ERROR/SoundPool(297): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
01-12 12:10:47.173: ERROR/SoundPool(297): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
01-12 12:10:47.183: ERROR/SoundPool(297): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
01-12 12:10:47.183: ERROR/SoundPool(297): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
01-12 12:10:49.543: ERROR/SoundPool(297): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
01-12 12:10:49.553: ERROR/SoundPool(297): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
01-12 12:10:49.553: ERROR/SoundPool(297): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
01-12 12:10:49.563: ERROR/SoundPool(297): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
01-12 12:10:49.563: ERROR/SoundPool(297): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
01-12 12:10:49.563: ERROR/SoundPool(297): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
01-12 12:10:49.573: ERROR/SoundPool(297): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
01-12 12:10:49.573: ERROR/SoundPool(297): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
01-12 12:10:49.573: ERROR/SoundPool(297): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
01-12 12:10:56.163: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1244): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getItem(ArrayAdapter.java:337)
at com.vallauri.TTS.myTTSActivity.combo(myTTSActivity.java:76)
at com.vallauri.TTS.myTTSActivity$1.onClick(myTTSActivity.java:65)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-12 12:10:57.973: ERROR/SoundPool(297): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
01-12 12:10:57.973: ERROR/SoundPool(297): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
01-12 12:10:57.983: ERROR/SoundPool(297): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
01-12 12:10:57.983: ERROR/SoundPool(297): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
01-12 12:10:57.983: ERROR/SoundPool(297): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
01-12 12:10:57.983: ERROR/SoundPool(297): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
01-12 12:10:57.993: ERROR/SoundPool(297): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
01-12 12:10:57.993: ERROR/SoundPool(297): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
01-12 12:10:58.003: ERROR/SoundPool(297): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
01-12 12:10:58.153: ERROR/InputDispatcher(297): channel '41bacb50 com.vallauri.TTS/com.vallauri.TTS.myTTSActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

Comment: show the adapter code and the get part

Comment: adapter.getItem(0); crash my app

Comment: post the stacktrace and show us more code.

Comment: Are you sure pref is not null?

Comment: Yes, the SharedPreferences work correctly and show me the strings in the AutoCompleteTextView

Comment: @user3144125 `new String[] {}` where is the data populated for string array??

Comment: You should paste the error too

Comment: Please write the logcat error

Comment: @user3144125 confirmation. there is no item `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0`. size is 0. Also if you add new item you should call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged`

Comment: ok but I have just added my string to the adapter (and work correctly), why seize is 0??

Comment: @user3144125 you din't do `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: @user3144125 add items to string array. then call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`. string array is empty.

Comment: yes, I have tried adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() but doesnt' work

Comment: @user3144125 have a array     `String array[] = new String[10];` Now use this `adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this,
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,
                array
        );` then  `array[0] ="item";
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        adapter.getItem(0);`

Comment: @user3144125 check my post will work

Comment: @user3144125 do not call notifyDataSetChanged() after add()ing to the ArrayAdapter since add() method already does it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a ArrayList

```
  ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Then

```
   adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,
            array
    );
```

Then

```
   array.add("item");
   dapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   String value =adapter.getItem(0);
   Log.i(".........",""+value);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missunderstanding the real use of an `ArrayAdapter`. You indeed should pass your adapter an ArrayList with the initial elements. If it's empty, it's ok too but you should keep the object of your ArrayList inside your class, so if you need to add an element to your ListView, you just add it to the ArrayList and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter. This way any change you do to the ArrayList is immediately propagated to your ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

For the crash: remove the last parameter of your adapter constructor.

And when you want to avoid duplicates, keep track (in a Map for example) what items you already added and don't add a new item if it's already in your map.